# Significado de la expresión "falsos patetismos"

Tags: modismos, expresiones, significado

Estaba leyendo el libro el mito de Sísifo y encontré esta oración: "Es curiosidad legítima preguntarse,claramente y sin **falsos patetismos**, si una conclusión de este orden exige abandonar cuanto antes una condición incomprensible "

Mi preguntas es, pues, qué significa la expresión "falsos patetismos" y cuál es su uso habitual?

Comment: Creo que el uso más común es en las descripciones de obras musicales y otras bellas artes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es ninguna expresión. "Patetismo" significa "cualidad de patético", y "[patético](https://dle.rae.es/?id=S9BD55e)" a su vez significa:

> 1. adj. Que conmueve profundamente o causa un gran dolor o tristeza.

Y "falso" significa falso :D

"Sin falsos patetismos" significa literalmente "sin fingir conmoción, dolor o tristeza".

No hay un "uso habitual" porque, como digo, no es una expresión fija. Es solo un sustantivo con un adjetivo delante.

Comment: Sugiero que aclares que el patetismo solo se refiere al 1.